# when we select textbox in page ,display the some text in another page during selecting that chk box

Tags: php, javascript, html

i designed 2 pages using html,here when we select checkbox in one page ,then i have to display some text in another page .how can i do this one.can any one help me.

the code in first page is

```
<p style="margin: 25px 0px 0px 10px; font:13px verdana;">would you like to show others to copy ?</p>

<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember1"  style="border: 0px;padding: 10px; margin-left:125px;font-size:12px;" />Yes<a href="#"></a><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember2" style="border: 0px;padding: 10px; margin-left:125px;font-size:12px;" />No<a href="#"></a>
```

here,when i select yes in this ,i have to display text as "you have to show others" .and 
when i select no ,it has to display as "you dont have permission to show others" .

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The only way for you is doing a form and to post it in the other page with _POST or _GET with a server side language like PHP ASP and so on, so when the user submit the form its showing on the other page whether you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to post that value to your server with a form or AJAX. Then during the process write that value to database. So you will know which file/page/copy/whatever will be shown or not.

--

(p.s. if it is just for a single use, try to assign the value to session variable -just in case if you don't have a database.-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you may use type="radio" to avoid that yes and no get both selected:

```
    <input onchange="setCookie('choice','yes');" type="radio" name="remember" id="remember1"
           style="border: 0px;padding: 10px; margin-left:125px;font-size:12px;" />Yes<a href="#"></a><br/>
    <input onchange="setCookie('choice','no');" type="radio" name="remember" id="remember2"
           style="border: 0px;padding: 10px; margin-left:125px;font-size:12px;" />No<a href="#"></a>
```

Then you may use cookies to pass the choice from one page to another. In the page of the input's:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        // set default
        document.getElementById("remember1").checked="true";
        setCookie('choice','yes');

        function setCookie(cookieName, cookieVal) {
            //alert("setCookie "+cookieName+"="+cookieVal);
            document.cookie=cookieName+"="+cookieVal;
        }
   </script>
```

And in the page where to recall the choice:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCookie(cookieName) {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for(var i = 0; i<cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].replace(/^\s+/, "");
                var nameVal = cookie.split("=");
                var name = nameVal[0];
                var val = cookie.substr(name.length+1);
                if(name==cookieName) return val;
            }
            return null;
        }
        alert(getCookie("choice"));
    </script>
```